# Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c++, openmp

I am running this C++ code using openMP.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

double fRand(double fMin, double fMax);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

int columns = 20;
int rows = 10000;

//Create 2D array table
double **table;
table = (double**) malloc( rows * sizeof( double *) );
for(int row=0; row<rows; row++) {
    table[row] = (double*) malloc( columns * sizeof( double ) );
}

//Generate random numbers
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<columns; j++) {
        table[i][j]=fRand(0,1000);
    }
}

//Create 2D array P
float **P;
P = (float**) malloc(rows * sizeof(float*));
for(int row=0; row<rows; row++) {
    P[row] = (float*) malloc(rows * sizeof(float));
}

//Compute P elements
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for(int j=i+1; j<rows; j++) {
        double d = 0;
        for(int k=0; k<columns; k++) {
            double df = table[i][k] - table[j][k];
            d += df * df;
        }
        P[i][j] = (float) d;
    }
}

std::cout << "Finish";

}

double fRand(double fMin, double fMax)
{
     double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
     return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}
```

When the number of rows is small (~10000), it is running fine and is making use of all the cores. However, when running the algorithm with a larger number of rows such as rows=120000, it crashes and i get the following error:

```
libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I tried to increase OMP_STACKSIZE but the error is still occuring.
I am using windows 10 64-bit. I have 128Gb of RAM and CPU has 32 cores.
I am compiling the code using the following command:

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -fopenmp myfile.cpp
```

Comment: you're not using ImageMagic, or some other library that uses threaded calculations? in somec ases there are conflicts with omp, if  some alternative method is used..only way to resolve is to limit\disable threading outside omp..

Comment: No, i am not using any library that uses threaded calculations.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and more information on compiler version, flags, and the system.

Comment: Your system is 64-bit, so make sure that you also build a 64-bit executable...

Comment: I am already using MinGW64

Comment: Tried to reproduce this on a Linux machine with just 16GB of RAM; couldn't reproduce the symptoms before it ground to a halt thrashing.  BTW, what's with all the `malloc()` when `auto **table = new double*[rows];` is much clearer?

Comment: Are you still using `columns=20` for `rows=120000`? Alywas check the return value of `malloc`! If you observe the application in a task manager, what memory usage do you see?